# Histograma de frecuencias con matplotlib. ¿Cómo mostrar el intervalo en el eje x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

Tengo una serie de números decimales que van de 0 a 15.

Estoy intentando mostrar un diagrama de frecuencias con barras con la librería de Python matplotlib. Quiero que los intervalos sean de 0, 1, ...., 15.

Creo que lo consigo añadiendo un array de bins, pues me muestra 15 barras. Sin embargo, los números de los intervalos no se muestran en el eje x, salen una serie de números decimales.

Hago lo siguiente:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#arrayIDx ~ array con valores decimales 
#en el intervalo 0-15.

plt.hist(arrayIdx,bins=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve salen una serie de números en el eje x.

¿Cómo hago para que salgan los enteros del 0 al 15?

Answer (score 1):

Lo he conseguido de la siguiente manera:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#arrayIDx ~ array con valores decimales 
#en el intervalo 0-15.
rangos = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]
plt.xticks(rangos, ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15"])
plt.hist(arrayIdx, bins = rangos)                         
plt.show()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]